# How to scale image from center? Windows 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, animation, windows-8.1

How to scale dynamic image control from the center programmatically in c# for Windows 8.1. This code scales image from left upper corner:

```
    Image img=new Image(){Width=150,Height=150};
    img.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
    Storyboard story = new Storyboard();

    DoubleAnimation xAnim = new DoubleAnimation();
    DoubleAnimation yAnim = new DoubleAnimation();

    xAnim.From = 0;
    yAnim.From = 0;
    xAnim.To = 1;
    yAnim.To = 0.5;

    xAnim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
    yAnim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500);

    story.Children.Add(xAnim);
    story.Children.Add(yAnim);

    Storyboard.SetTarget(xAnim, img);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(yAnim, img);

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(xAnim, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(yAnim, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)");

    story.Begin();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
img.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
```

That will mean that all of your transforms will be relative to the center of your image. See the [RenderTransformOrigin documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.rendertransformorigin.aspx) for more details.